# SQLAlchemy: assign TypeDecorator for the mapping generated via automap

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy has two abilities:

1. [reflect database to create mapping in runtime](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html)
2. [and customize columns type conversion](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#overriding-type-compilation)

I would like to combine these abilities: reflect database and then assign TypeDecorator for specific columns of specific tables.

I have spent a lot of time trying to do this but had no result. The SQLAlchemy manual does not describe how to assign TypeDecorator for the  mapping generated via automap.

I would like to know whether it's possible and if yes, how to achive my goal.

Thank you!